# Building Cryptonote source with Boost on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, boost, cmake

I'm trying to build Cryptonote source from GitHub - https://github.com/cryptonotefoundation/cryptonote

I've already successful complete building on Unix, but on Windows I have some problems with that.

I've install on my Windows 10 x64:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
- Git
- CMake 3.10.1
- Python 2.7.9

Then I'm trying build and install

- Boost 1.55.0

Downloaded "boost_1_55_0.zip" from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.55.0/

After unpacking I run from cmd

```
bootstrap.bat
```

Next I enter

```
.\b2
```

When build is done let's do install

```
.\b2 --toolset=msvc-12.0 --build-type=complete --prefix=D:\Boost install
```

Ok next is build Cryptonote sources, going to C:\cryptonote, create dir "build" and enter to "build" dir.

Now I trying to build Cryptonote by entering this

```
cmake -DBOOST_ROOT:PATHNAME=D:\Boost -g "Visual Studio 2012 Win64" ..
```

Here is output:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 12 2013
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.31101.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.31101.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1928 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.55.0

  Boost include path: D:/Boost/include/boost-1_55

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_serialization

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:112 (find_package)


-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Python27/python.exe (found version "2.7.9")
CMake Warning in CMakeLists.txt:
  CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RULES was enabled even though installation rules have
  been specified


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/cryptonote/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/cryptonote/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Where I can find that library? Or what I need to do for complete build? Thank you!

Comment: cmake prints suggestion how to fix this at the end of the log.

Comment: D:\Boost\lib really doesn't have "boost_serialization" DLL file, all other library there, before I have similar error but Boost can't find other library, so I rebuild boost, reinstall and now have this problem.

Comment: Then it should be reflected in the boost build log why it was skipped or failed to build. Also "Visual Studio 2013" but command is `-g "Visual Studio 2012`

Comment: CMakeErrorLog

https://pastebin.com/qcSA9RJ1